# Vertical alignment of labels next to checkbox in inline unordered list IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml, vertical-alignment

This fiddle aligns vertically in FFOX4, IE8 but the label text appears slighlty out of line in IE7.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hQ8e/1/

Is there any way to fix this other than with hacks/conditional CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your CSS:

```
.selection label{padding:0; width:auto; vertical-align:bottom;}
```

And replace with the following CSS:

```
.selection label{float: none; padding:0; width:auto; vertical-align:middle;}
.selection input{float: none}
```

Comment: I don't think vertical-align: center is a valid value of the property so used middle instead which worked fine.  Forgot that you can't apply vertical align to block/floated elements.

Comment: @RyanP13 - Sorry about that - must have been day dreaming but I'm glad you got it working and I have ammended my answer accordingly. Just out of interest, if you asked for an answer that did not require conditional CSS why did you accept an answer that requires conditional CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Check boxes have a "hard" margin in older IE. Give them `margin: -3px` in a style sheet specifically for IE < 8.

Comment: sorry My Head hurts is more correct for answering the issue without conditional CSS.  Still get an up vite from me :)